# Issue installing RPi.GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I'm trying to install RPi.GPIO and every time I run `sudo python setup.py install` I run into these messages on my console:

```
source/c_gpio.c:99:13: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
                 fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);

source/c_gpio.c:116:15: warning: ‘peri_base’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     gpio_base = peri_base + GPIO_BASE_OFFSET;

source/cpuinfo.c:41:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
       fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp);

source/event_gpio.c:75:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     write(fd, str_gpio, len);
```

When I attempt to import RPi.GPIO into a python file I get an error message saying there is no module named GPIO. Does anyone know any solutions?